# Program escalates itself from admin to system

Tags: c, windows, winapi, elevated-privileges

I wrote a program that needs to be running as SYSTEM. I add the linker option 'UAC Execution Level' to 'requireAdministrator' and it pops the UAC like it should but now I need to escalate from admin to SYSTEM how can I do that?
I thought about opening the program's token and inject it the SYSTEM token but it is not legit way. How can I do it neatly because I know once you admin you can be SYSTEM.

Comment: Run it as a service under the local system account. Of course, one wonders why you feel the need to do this at all.

Comment: you can get token from system process or impersonate system thread, if you have debug privileges. and impersonate some your thread(s) with this system token, when you need do some task as *LocalSystem*. and anyway - what concrete you need ? some concrete privileges ? be membership of *S-1-5-18* or what ?

Comment: @RbMm I need in my program to load a driver. I am creating and starting a new service for the driver. My program also has GUI so I think I will load the driver with a thread running as system like you said

Comment: but in this case i not understand for what you need run as `SYSTEM`. for load driver direct, via `ZwLoadDriver` you need `SE_LOAD_DRIVER_PRIVILEGE` privilege enabled (it usually have by admins). or if you do this via service manager - for create service you need be member of *Administrators*. for start already existing service - depend from it security descriptor but usually you also need be member of *Administrators*. in all case you not need *SYSTEM* token

Comment: @RbMm I have just realized I confused this with some other thing and when I tested the program with admin it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Write a windows service. It will run as `SYSTEM` user by default.

A simple tutorial is [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sergey_babkins_blog/2016/12/28/windows-service-wrapper-in-c/), but remember that installing a service requires administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Once you're running as administrator, here are some options:

1. If you know you're not going to be using GUI functions, you can create a scheduled task that runs your same exe as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM within a few seconds, and check within your code which account the process is running as.

Copied from a project of mine and slightly modified:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinNls.h>
#include <shobjidl.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#include <ObjIdl.h>
#include <ShlGuid.h>
#include <taskschd.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "taskschd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")

HRESULT WINAPI CreateSchedTask(WCHAR *wszExePath)
{
    ITaskService *pService = NULL;
    ITaskFolder *pRoot = NULL;
    ITaskDefinition *pTask = NULL;
    ITaskSettings *pSettings = NULL;
    IRegistrationInfo *pInfo = NULL;
    ITriggerCollection *pCollection = NULL;
    ITrigger *pTrigger = NULL;
    ITimeTrigger *pTime = NULL;
    IPrincipal *pPrincipal = NULL;
    IActionCollection *pActionCollection = NULL;
    IAction *pAction = NULL;
    IExecAction *pExecAction = NULL;
    IRegisteredTask *pRegTask = NULL;
    SYSTEMTIME stNow;
    FILETIME ftStart, ftEnd;
    ULARGE_INTEGER ulWork;
    WCHAR wFmt[100];
    VARIANT vBlank = _variant_t();

    if (FAILED(CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)))
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    //CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITaskService, (LPVOID *) &pService)))
    {
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    pService->Connect(vBlank, vBlank, vBlank, vBlank);
    pService->GetFolder(SysAllocString(L"\\"), &pRoot);
    pService->NewTask(0, &pTask);
    pService->Release();
    pTask->get_RegistrationInfo(&pInfo);
    pInfo->put_Author(SysAllocString(L"TASKNAMEHERE"));
    pInfo->Release();
    

    pTask->get_Settings(&pSettings);
    pSettings->put_StartWhenAvailable(VARIANT_TRUE);
    pSettings->put_Enabled(VARIANT_TRUE);
    pSettings->Release();
    

    pTask->get_Triggers(&pCollection);
    pCollection->Create(TASK_TRIGGER_TIME, &pTrigger);
    pCollection->Release();
    pTrigger->QueryInterface(IID_ITimeTrigger, (LPVOID *)&pTime);

    GetLocalTime(&stNow);
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&stNow, &ftStart);
    ulWork.HighPart = ftStart.dwHighDateTime;
    ulWork.LowPart = ftStart.dwLowDateTime;
                     //20000000000 
    ulWork.QuadPart += 300000000UI64;
    ftStart.dwHighDateTime = ulWork.HighPart;
    ftStart.dwLowDateTime = ulWork.LowPart;
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftStart, &stNow);

    // Note: replace -07:00 with the appropriate UTC offset for your time zone
    StringCchPrintfW(wFmt, 100, L"%.4hu-%.2hu-%.2huT%.2hu:%.2hu:%.2hu-07:00", stNow.wYear, stNow.wMonth, stNow.wDay, stNow.wHour, stNow.wMinute, stNow.wSecond);
    pTime->put_StartBoundary(SysAllocString(wFmt));
    ulWork.QuadPart += 900000000UI64;
    ftEnd.dwLowDateTime = ulWork.LowPart;
    ftEnd.dwHighDateTime = ulWork.HighPart;
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftEnd, &stNow);
    StringCchPrintfW(wFmt, 100, L"%.4hu-%.2hu-%.2huT%.2hu:%.2hu:%.2hu-07:00", stNow.wYear, stNow.wMonth, stNow.wDay, stNow.wHour, stNow.wMinute, stNow.wSecond);
    pTime->put_EndBoundary(SysAllocString(wFmt));
    pTime->put_Id(SysAllocString(L"TimeTrigger"));
    pTime->Release();

    pTask->get_Actions(&pActionCollection);
    pActionCollection->Create(TASK_ACTION_EXEC, &pAction);
    pActionCollection->Release();
    pAction->QueryInterface(IID_IExecAction, (LPVOID *)&pExecAction);
    pAction->Release();

    pExecAction->put_Path(SysAllocString(wszExePath));
    pExecAction->Release();
    pTask->get_Principal(&pPrincipal);
    pPrincipal->put_RunLevel(TASK_RUNLEVEL_HIGHEST);
    pPrincipal->put_LogonType(TASK_LOGON_SERVICE_ACCOUNT);
    pTask->put_Principal(pPrincipal);
    pPrincipal->Release();

    pRoot->RegisterTaskDefinition(
        SysAllocString(L"System Elevation"),
        pTask, TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
        _variant_t(L"NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM"),
        _variant_t(), TASK_LOGON_SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
        _variant_t(L""), &pRegTask);

    pRoot->Release();
    pTask->Release();
    pRegTask->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return S_OK;
}


INT APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, INT nShowCmd)
{
    WCHAR wUsername[100], wExePath[MAX_PATH];
    GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"USERNAME", wUsername, 100);
    
    if (!wcschr(wUsername, L'$'))
    {
        GetModuleFileNameW(hInstance, wExePath, MAX_PATH);
        CreateSchedTask(wExePath);
    }
    else
    {
        // NOTE: MessageBox and other GUI functions won't work since the process isn't running in winsta0\default
        // File I/O instead
        HANDLE hLog = CreateFileW(L"C:\\Temp\\Log.txt", GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        DWORD dwWritten;
        UINT uLen;
        CHAR szBuf[100];
        SetFilePointer(hLog, 0, NULL, FILE_END);
        StringCchPrintfA(szBuf, 100, "Hello from %S\r\n", wUsername);
        StringCbLengthA(szBuf, 100, &uLen);
        WriteFile(hLog, szBuf, uLen, &dwWritten, NULL);
        CloseHandle(hLog);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

2. Use the Windows Process API to elevate to System. I don't have much in the way of example code for this, but you can look at [PAExec](https://github.com/poweradminllc/PAExec), an open source alternative to SysInternals PSExec tool, that allows creating new interactive processes as System.
3. The idiomatic way of doing this on Windows, which is create a Windows service.